# tableselect checkboxes

Tags: forms

i want to change values of only checked elements on tableselect.
How can i do that please ?

this is my tableselect :

```
$form['tab'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('empty !'),

);
return $form;
```

i've also a submit button that makes changes (update database) on one column of the tableselect :

```
 $form['published'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Publish'),
        '#states' => array(
            'invisible' => array(
            ':input[name="select_list"]' => array('value' => 'Published'),
            )
            ),
        '#submit'=> array('publish_submit'),
    );
```

My function to make changes (to publish elements that aren't now) :

```
function publish_submit($form, &$form_state){
$check = $form_state['values']['tab'];
//$check = array_filter($form_state['values']['tab']);

$sql = db_update('field_data_field_books');
$sql->fields(array('field_books_value'=> 'Published')); 
$sql->condition('entity_id',$check); //update only books i checked on the tableselect
$query = $sql->execute();
   }
```

this is what dsm($check) returns (when i check one or more elements on the tableselect )

[image]

this is dsm($rows) (6 elements are ok):

[image]

[image]

This is how i created the $rows :

```
$rows = array();



foreach ($result as $res){

    $rows [] = array(

            'book_title' => l($res-> field_title_value, 'node/'.$res->entity_id),
            'book_state' => $res-> field_state_value,
            'book_editor' => $res-> field_editor_value,
            'book_categories' => $res-> name,
            'edit_books'=>l(t('Details'), 'node/'.$res->entity_id.'/edit'),
          );

}

$form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#empty' => t('nothing!'),

);
```

Comment: Well first you should check the structure of `$check` variable. You can just `var_dump($check); die();` or use something like devel module and `dpm($check);`. It needs to be a simple array of id's. Then you need to put the condition as "IN" like so: `$sql->condition('entity_id', $check, 'IN');`. That would updated the `field_books_value` to `Published` on all id's contained in `$check`. See "Array Operators" on the [Conditional Clauses documenation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/310086).

Comment: Thnx beebee, first i've changed : $check = array_filter($form_state['values']['tab']); to $check = $form_state['values']['tab']; and when i do dsm($check), it returns :  ... (Array, 9 elements)

    0 (String, 1 characters ) 0 (this is because i checked the first item)
    1 (Integer) 0
    2 (Integer) 0  do you think i'm getting the real checked value ?

Comment: please check the picture i've just added bellow

Comment: `dsm($rows);` and put 1 row's structure in the question too. I suppose you you looked at the [#tableselect Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect)

Comment: yes i looked at it but nothing about the checkbox values

Comment: There's your problem, if you look at the documentation, you should be indexing your array with your entity's id. Look at the row on the example in the documentation linked above: `$options[$node->nid] = array(...`. You need to look at how you're generating `$rows`.

Comment: Sorry in the last picture, i've changed header's tableselect and options..ect to french language (the web site is in french)

Comment: yes that's right but in my case i'm indexing my options with values of header

Comment: Hi beebee, I was workin on another stuff but I'm still no resolving this problem, Why should I put 'entity_id' on the condition? I have no entity_id equals to any of what dsm shows with dsm($check)

Comment: Dsm($check) returns the position of what i checked on the tableselect, how to get all information of what I've checked ?

Comment: You need to show us how you're creating `$rows` that gets assigned to the tableselect as `#options`. This `$rows` array needs to be an associative array, associated by the entity's ID. So if you're including node with id 321 in the array it should read: `$rows[321] = array(...);`. Then tableselect should give you the correct ID's in `$check`. Please put how you created `$rows` in the question.

Comment: Hi beebee, I've just added my rows on my question

Comment: You're right beebee thank you thank you thank you !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As beebee said on comments :

$rows should be indexed like this :

```
foreach ($result as $res){

    $rows [$res -> entity_id] = array(
```

and the condition of the publishing function :

```
function publishing_submit($form, &$form_state){

    $check = array_filter($form_state['values']['table']);
    $sql = db_update('field_data_field_state');
    $sql->fields(array('field_state_value'=> 'Published'));
    $sql->condition('entity_id', $check, 'IN');
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Thanx beebee